# What are really the real consequences to malloc() calls without free()? can it make a program going to crazy,such as a forever loop?

Tags: c, linux, 32-bit, icc

I have a big problem in my current program. Inside on loop,two functions if I do another function call inside this loop,I get a forever loop! even a `printf("bah");` give a forever loop.

This give normal execution.

```
//size = 10 (example)
while(size > 0) {
  a(); // decrement by 2
  b(); // decrement by 2
}
```

But

```
//size = 10 (example)
while(size > 0) {
a(); // decrement by 2
b(); // decrement by 2
putchar(' ');
}
```

Give a forever loop. The single different is the `putchar()` call.

It's hard to assume something,but some idea to what is happing?

What `a() and`b()` functions do basically is:

get two structs from an array,decrement `size` by `1` and `printf()` some of its members. Such structures aren't freed(yet) only at program end up.

I posted this part of code to tro to get some idea to what is(posibly) happing. All code from this part of code was get is really big(to be posted here for us read).

**EDIT:**

Here's a minimal `a()` and `b()` implmentation:

```
void a(void) {
  foo_t* f = top;
  while(f->y == STATE_X) {
  get(&a); get(&b); /* it's equivalent to pop() in a linked list. size is size=size-1 in each get call() */
  printf("%d,%d\n",a->x,ab->x);
  f = f->next;
 }
 top = f;
}

void a(void) {
  foo_t* f = top;
  while(f->y == STATE_Y) {
  get(&a); get(&b); /* it's equivalent to pop() in a linked list. size is size=size-1 in each get call() */
  printf("%d,%d\n",a->x,ab->x);
  f = f->next;
 }
 top = f;
}
```

`get()` - is my equivalent to `pop()` in my context.

`top`   - points to last `struct footype` processed from stack.

`size`  - count of elements currently on stack.

`struct footype` is implemeted as linked this too,there's a `prev` and `next` that points to previously and next member of it.

Comment: I think you should post more code

Comment: No, memory allocation (unless you're running out of memory, then...it depends on your code) won't cause an infinite loop. You're doing something _bad_ inside your functions (probably with pointers unless there is a mistake with "size"). Try to write a small functional example here, probably writing it you'll see what's wrong too (and we'll have enough information to give a proper answer).

Comment: It would help if you show us simplified code for a() and b()... is `size` globally defined by the way?

Comment: That's ok,I will post some code. Wait.

Comment: @HarryK.: Yes. It's a global variable.

Comment: @Jack: Cool! Waiting for code of a() and b() (simplified if possible)

Comment: Updated! I tried do some explanation about my context to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: @Jack: Not as simplified as I would expect :LOL: Anyway, any chances that the while loops are not entered at all? Say because neither condition is met regarding the state?

Comment: @Jack: Or any chances that `get()` does not decrease `size`, say for example when applied to a an empty list?

Comment: TOO. MANY. GLOBALS!!!

Comment: Consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or some other memory leak detector.

Comment: @HarryK.: `a()` and `b()` are almost a copy of real code. In case of `get()` doesn't decrease `size`,it happen in the case of `loop2` only. In the loop1,it works normally.

Comment: @JohnBode: All functions in the program needs to access `size` value. Should I to pass in each function call a copy of `size`?

Comment: @Jack: Ideally, all functions should communicate through parameters and return values, rather than share state through globals.  Sharing state this way promotes *tight coupling*, making code hard to reuse between programs.  It can also introduce maintenance headaches, and I think it's contributing to your problem.

Comment: @Jack: And to expand on Harry K.'s comment, what happens in a `get` call if the list is empty?

Comment: @JohnBode: there's a check in the function. If `size==0` a function called `error` print an error message on `stderr` and call `exit` and returns a `EXIT_FAILURE`. Also,I will consider to remove such globals variables,let's me try to first fix this current bug. if I take a "long time" to find it,I remove the globals before.

Comment: @Jack, actually I agree with JohnBode that you should limit global side-effects to the absolute minimum (ideally to none, but I know that's not as easy as it sounds). It's quite difficult to find what's going wrong with the code you posted, since it seems to depend on side-effects coming form lots of different places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we go purely by what you say about the code that's not showing -- that the memory is allocated, but never freed -- then that memory will remain allocated until the program ends.  If you continue to allocate more memory without freeing any, eventually you'll run out...at which point `malloc` may start failing and returning null pointers.  (And of course, attempting to access memory via a null pointer can cause all kinds of wackiness to ensue, if we go by the C standard.  The most common result in Linux, though, is a segfault.)

However, absent a `ulimit` setting, you'll probably use up all the swap space as well, which can cause a huge slowdown toward the end.  And of course, using all that memory up in your process, takes it away from other processes.  Eventually, one of two things is likely to happen:

- The other processes may start failing to allocate memory...and if they haven't accounted for that, they may break.
- Linux will intentionally hand out imaginary memory -- basically, memory pages backed by neither RAM nor swap space. (The reasons for this are a bit complicated, but make sense in context.)  Only when a process tries to actually use that memory does the kernel scrounge up some RAM for it.  And if there's no free RAM and no room to swap, the kernel will kill an existing process to reclaim its virtual memory.

  (If it goes that far, there's an algorithm that decides which process to kill.  It will generally prefer the process that's the worst offender memorywise -- which, in this case, is probably yours.)

That's about the extent of the damage, though.  You'll slow things down quite a bit, and mess with other processes, and possibly get one of them killed (likely yours).

One thing it won't do, at least on its own, is cause loops to continue forever.  In order for it to cause that, the program would have to (1) check for failure, and (2) loop forever retrying a failed operation til it succeeded, without changing anything relevant to the operation.

Something else is going on here.

Comment: @Jack: It's a program, shell command, and/or system call (depending on context) that lets you get/set various resource limits for your (process|shell) and its children.  One of those limits is the amount of memory the OS will let them use up.